# Apache CXF returns HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type after upgrading TomEE 9.0.0-M2 to 9.0.0-M7

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee, http-status-code-415

I wrote a simple RestApi a year ago which runs without any problems on Tomee Plus 9.0.0-M2. Now  I downloaded the newest Tomee Plus 9.0.0-M7 and get following response on every request:

HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

**The console output is:**

```
No message body reader has been found for class controller.controller.TestRequest, ContentType: application/json
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: jakarta.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1427)
```

I don't use any Framework like Spring or so.
What happenend to the Tomee? Is some configuration missing?